# Dotnetzip OverflowException

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I'm developing in C#, and using Dotnetzip's Source code to get the application in one file.

But when running, i get the exception:

```
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
   at Ionic.Crc.CRC32..ctor(Int32 polynomial, Boolean reverseBits) in DotNetZip\CRC32.cs:line 452
   at Ionic.Crc.CRC32..ctor(Boolean reverseBits) in DotNetZip\CRC32.cs:line 418
   at Ionic.Crc.CRC32..ctor() in DotNetZip\CRC32.cs:line 398
   at Ionic.Crc.CrcCalculatorStream..ctor(Boolean leaveOpen, Int64 length, Stream stream, CRC32 crc32) in DotNetZip\CRC32.cs:line 622
   at Ionic.Crc.CrcCalculatorStream..ctor(Stream stream) in DotNetZip\CRC32.cs:line 519
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.ExtractOne(Stream output) in DotNetZip\ZipEntry.Extract.cs:line 1043
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.InternalExtract(String baseDir, Stream outstream, String password) in DotNetZip\ZipEntry.Extract.cs:line 870
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Extract(String baseDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction extractExistingFile) in DotNetZip\ZipEntry.Extract.cs:line 240
   at ItxInstaller.Package.GetData(String instFilePath) in Package.cs:line 32
   at ItxInstaller.Install..ctor() in Install.cs:line 26
   at ItxInstaller.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 54
```

The Install.cs is like this:

```
public Install()
{
    // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Package pack = Package.GetData(Program.args[1]);
    this.Title.Text = pack.AppName;
    this.PathBox.Text = pack.GeneratePath();
}
```

The Package.cs contains the GetData():

```
class Package
    {
        public string AppName;
        public string ExePath;

        private string FilePath;

        public Package(string filePath)
        {
            this.ValueInit(filePath);
            this.FilePath = filePath;
        }

        public static Package GetData(string instFilePath)
        {
            using (ZipFile Package = ZipFile.Read(instFilePath))
            {
                Package["app.itx"].Extract(Path.GetTempPath(), ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }

            return new Package(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "app.itx"));
        }
}
```

How to solve this exception?

Comment: If you built dotnetzip from source then check the project's build settings.  Sounds like you turned on the "Check for arithmetic overflow" option in the Advanced Build Settings dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the unchecked() flag to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem with Mono when using "-checked+" as parameter, i.e. with enabled arithmetic checks. Omitting this parameter results in a working executable.

There is also a project setting for it in Visual Studio.

I've extracted the relevant code into this working program so you can test it yourself:

```
using System;

namespace Test {
    public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
            CRC32 test = new CRC32();
            Console.Out.WriteLine(test.dwPolynomial);
        }
    }

    public class CRC32 {
        public UInt32 dwPolynomial;

        public CRC32() : this(false) {
        }

        public CRC32(bool reverseBits) :
            this(unchecked((int)0xEDB88320), reverseBits) {
        }

        public CRC32(int polynomial, bool reverseBits) {
            this.dwPolynomial = (uint) polynomial; // this is line 452
        }
    }
}
```

Using `dcms test.cs && mono test.exe` runs fine.

Using `dcms -checked+ test.cs && mono test.exe` results in a

```
Unhandled Exception: System.OverflowException: Number overflow.
    at Test.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.OverflowException: Number overflow.
    at Test.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

**Update:** if you can't or don't want to disable arithmetic checks then you could modify the source code of like 452 to

```
this.dwPolynomial = unchecked((uint) polynomial);
```

This turns off arithmetic checks for the expression.

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved the problem by unchecked() flag.